# Embedding Media Players for streaming audio

Tags: embed, audio-streaming, winamp

I already know that there are flash and html5 players that can effectively stream a shoutcast source. I also know that I can simply add a link to the .pls and have it open. I know that I can't force a specific player to be used on a users system. I've looked through various questions on this site and haven't actually found a solution. 
I know that if I use a simple href command and point it to an m3u file I can pop open a window and then it will load whatever audio player a user has set as a default player. What I would like to do is provide a way for a person to click on a link for a specific type of player and then have that open an embedded player of that type. If the user does not have that plug-in or player installed it will offer the option to dowload and install. I've figured out how to embed a windows media player and a quicktime player but I haven't yet figured out how to embed real audio or a "default" (winamp vlc media) player. I'm hoping someone has an idea on how to accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is embed the right content, and the system will use whatever plugin has registered itself to handle that content type.

```
<embed src="somefile.ra" />
```

Comment: Will that work for a shoutcast stream? Will it cause the stream to be opened in whatever the default player is?

Comment: @myth024, Yes, it will.  I also recommend adding a semicolon at the end of your URL, in case a Mozilla-compatible user agent tries to play the audio.  (This would be SHOUTcast only... for example, your URL could be `http://1.2.3.4:8000/;`)

Comment: Just a note:If you enter in the URL of a icecast or shoutcast stream the same way you would for an html5 audio and then add a /listen.pls OR listen.ram etc. So <audio src="http://ipaddress:port/listen.asx> After reading the answer, I discovered this was the best way. How a computer opens a .pls or a .ram file is out of my control.. so a standard link like.. <a href="streamingauidoip:port/listen.pls">OPEN</a> will work to prompt the browser to do whatever it's set to do with a .pls file. The .pls file doesn't have to actually exist on the server.